# Does this Lagrangian density represent anything "real"?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, classical-field-theory

So this lagrangian was used as an example for deriving the equations of motion using the Euler-Lagrange equations in our lecture notes.

$$ L (\phi )=-\phi (x,t)^{2}+m\left(\frac{\partial \phi }{\partial x}\right)^{2}-c\frac{\partial \phi }{\partial t}\frac{\partial \phi }{\partial x}$$

but im wondering if it describes any "real" system or if its just some generic lagrangian conjured up for this specific example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just the usual Klein-Gordon Lagrangian in a weird set of coordinates.  Specifically, if we define
$$
\tau = \frac{2 \sqrt{m}}{c}t + \frac{1}{\sqrt{m}} x , \qquad \xi = \frac{1}{\sqrt{m}} x,
$$
then we have
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x} &= \frac{\partial \xi}{\partial x} \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \xi} + \frac{\partial \tau}{\partial x} \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \tau} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{m}} \left[\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \xi} + \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \tau} \right] \\
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t} &= \frac{\partial \xi}{\partial t} \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \xi} + \frac{\partial \tau}{\partial t} \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \tau} = \frac{2 \sqrt{m}}{c}  \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \tau}
\end{align*}
and so
\begin{align*}
m\left(\frac{\partial \phi }{\partial x}\right)^{2}-c\frac{\partial \phi }{\partial t}\frac{\partial \phi }{\partial x} &= \left[\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \xi} + \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \tau} \right]^2 - 2 \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \tau} \left[\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \xi} + \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \tau} \right] = \left(\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \xi} \right)^2- \left(\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \tau} \right)^2.
\end{align*}
I kind of doubt that this was your instructor's intention, but there's not a lot of freedom in writing out second-order kinetic terms, and it turns out there are only a few possible "canonical forms" such as this one.

Comment: Yeah makes sense I couldnt figure out what system it was supposed to describe then. Guess it is just inteded as an example. Thanks alot mate!